# Is std::ifstream significantly slower than FILE?

Tags: c++, optimization, file-io, ifstream

I've been informed that my library is slower than it should be, on the order of 30+ times too slow parsing a particular file (text file, size 326 kb). The user suggested that it may be that I'm using `std::ifstream` (presumably instead of `FILE`).

I'd rather not blindly rewrite, so I thought I'd check here first, since my guess would be the bottleneck is elsewhere. I'm reading character by character, so the only functions I'm using are `get()`, `peek()`, and `tellg()/seekg()`.

**Update:**

I profiled, and got [confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485649/confusing-gprof-output) output - gprof didn't appear to think that it took so long. I rewrote the program to read the entire file into a buffer first, and it sped up by about 100x. I think the problem may have been the `tellg()/seekg()` that took a long time, but gprof may have been unable to see that for some reason. In any case, `ifstream` does *not* appear to buffer the entire file, even for this size.

Comment: [Long live **gprof**, as a museum piece.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485649/confusing-gprof-output/1786067#1786067)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't think that'd make a difference. Especially if you're reading char by char, the overhead of I/O is likely to completely dominate *anything* else. 
Why do you read single bytes at a time? You know how extremely inefficient it is?

On a 326kb file, the fastest solution will most likely be to just read it into memory at once.

The difference between std::ifstream and the C equivalents, is basically a virtual function call or two. It may make a difference if executed a few tens of million times per second, otherwise, not reall. file I/O is generally so slow that the API used to access it doesn't really matter. What matters far more is the read/write pattern. Lots of seeks are bad, sequential reads/writes good.

Comment: Actually, I didn't know how inefficient it is. I just assumed that behind the scenes, it read it into memory. I guess I'll do that instead.

Comment: Some input streams are buffered. If your code reads one char at a time it doesn't mean that underlying stream does that too.

Comment: Both FILE and fstream are buffered (although the buffer maybe too small), linux heavily optimizes disk access, so your file which is relatively small will be loaded in memory (windows also does this).

Comment: Depends on how much it buffers and such. I'm willing to bet that reading the entire file in one go will still be faster.

Comment: @jalf: Easy statement to make. It may be faster but I am willing to bet not signioficantly.

Comment: I have a feeling he is Read->Process->Write pattern, per char. All buffering strategies go to hell then.

Answer (score 4):

It should be slightly slower, but like what you said, it might not be the bottleneck. Why don't you profile your program and see if that's the case?

Answer (score 3):

All benchmarks are evil. Just profile your code for the data you expect.

I performed an I/O performance comparison between Ruby, Python, Perl, C++ once. For my data, languages versions, etc C++'s variant was several times slower (it was a big suprise at that time).

Comment: What about C? I'd be very surprised if any of the mentioned languages besides C++ was operating faster than C.

Comment: @rr- if your disk can't provide data faster than 100M/s then it doesn't matter that your C program may process 1G/s. As other answers have said already, disk i/o is typically much slower than anything else in your program. See related questions on I/O performance: [Why is reading lines from stdin much slower in C++ than Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371238/why-is-reading-lines-from-stdin-much-slower-in-c-than-python) and [Reading in an entire file at once in C++, part 2](http://insanecoding.blogspot.ru/2011/11/reading-in-entire-file-at-once-in-c.html)

Comment: In your post you said C++ was behaving the worst among Ruby, Python and others. This should have nothing to do with I/O performance, which is a bottleneck for *all* of these languages uniformly. And that's where I'd be surprised to find out that C is behaving worse than Ruby, for example, mainly because Ruby is written in C.

Comment: @rr-:1. if I/O dominates; language doesn't matter unless you're Google. 2. If the file is cached then read the links I've provided to see how programs written in the same language may show different performance results for the same problem

Answer (score 3):

I thinks that is unlikely your problem will be fixed by switching from fstream to FILE*, usually both are buffered by the C library. Also the OS can cache reads (linux is very good in that aspect). Given the size of the file you are accessing is pretty likely it will be entirely in RAM.

Like PolyThinker say your best bet is to run your program trough an profiler an determine where the problem is.

Also you are using seekg/tellg this can cause notable delays if your disk is heavily fragmented, because to read the file for the first time the disk have to move the heads to the correct position.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that you should profile. But if you're reading the file a character at a time, how about creating a memory-mapped file? That way you can treat the file like an array of characters, and the OS should take care of all the low-level buffering for you. The simplest and probably fastest solution is a win in my book. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997131/stdfstream-buffering-vs-manual-buffering-why-10x-gain-with-manual-buffering) is an excellent benchmark which shows that under extreme conditions, `fstream`s are actually quite slow... unless:

1. You use buffering (I cannot stress that enough)
2. You manipulate the buffer yourself (that is, if you need performance such as OP in the linked question), which is not so different from using `FILE*`.

You shouldn't optimize prematurely, though. `fstreams` are generally better, and if you need to optimize them down in the road, you can always do it later with little cost. In order to prepare for the worst in advance, I suggest creating a minimal proxy for `fstream` now so that you can optimize it later, without need to touch anything else.