# Confusing gprof output

Tags: c++, optimization, profiling, gprof

I ran `gprof` on a C++ program that took `16.637s`, according to `time()`, and I got this for the first line of output:

```
%   cumulative   self              self     total           
time   seconds   seconds    calls   s/call   s/call  name    
31.07      0.32     0.32  5498021     0.00     0.00  [whatever]
```

Why does it list `31.07%` of time if it only took `.32` seconds? Is this a per-call time? (Wouldn't that be self s/call?)

This is my first time using `gprof`, so please be kind :)

Edit: by scrolling down, it appears that gprof only thinks my program takes 1.03 seconds. Why might it be getting it so wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bottleneck turned out to be in file I/O (see [Is std::ifstream significantly slower than FILE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477225/is-stdifstream-significantly-slower-than-file)). I switched to reading the entire file in a buffer and it sped up enormously.

The problem here was that gprof doesn't appear to generate accurate profiling when waiting for file I/O (see http://www.regatta.cs.msu.su/doc/usr/share/man/info/ru_RU/a_doc_lib/cmds/aixcmds2/gprof.htm). In fact, `seekg` and `tellg` were not even on the profiling list, and they were the bottleneck!

Comment: Right. `gprof` will ignore any code that isn't instrumented, usually including time spend in stdlib and system calls. Getting accurate profiling information for I/O- and allocation-bound programs can be tricky.

Comment: I've just had this same problem. Bravo for providing this.

Answer (score 6):

**Self seconds** is the time spent in [whatever].

**Cumulative seconds** is the time spent in [whatever] and the calls above it (such as [whatever] + main)

**Neither of those include time spent in functions called from [whatever].**  That's why you're not seeing more time listed.

If your [whatever] function is calling lots of printf's, for example, your gprof output is telling you that printf is eating the majority of that time.

Comment: Actually, I had a program with a function that called _no_ other functions, yet had a similar issue.  By tuning this function, much more time was saved than suggested by gprof.

Comment: The percentage time is ONLY the time spent in the function in question.  Obviously so, else "main" would be the top function in every gprof profile.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a pretty good overview of [how to read gprof output](http://badgertronics.com/writings/gprof.html).  The 31.07% you are looking at is portion of the total run time gprof thinks is being spent in just that function (not including functions it calls).  Odds are the reason the percentage is so large while the time is small is that gprof thinks the program doesn't take as long as you do.  This is easily checked by scrolling down this first section of the gprof output: cumulative seconds will keep getting larger and larger until it limits out at the total running time of the program (from gprof's perspective).  I think you will find this is about one second rather than the 16 you are expecting.

As for why there is such a large discrepancy there, I can't say.  Perhaps gprof isn't seeing all of the code.  Or did you use time on the instrumented code while it was profiling?  I wouldn't expect that to work correctly...

Comment: I did use time on the instrumented code, but I also checked it on several runs of non-instrumented code, and pretty close (within a second).

Comment: Did you check (like I suggested) to see what gprof thinks the total time of the run was?

Comment: Yeah, it's 1.03 seconds. Why is might it getting it so wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried some of the other tools mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux)?  It would be interesting how they compare.

Answer (score 1):

You're experiencing a problem common to **gprof** and other profilers based on the same concepts - 1) sample the program counter to get some kind of histogram, 2) instrument the functions to measure times, counts, and get a call graph.

For actually locating performance problems, they are missing the point.
It's not about measuring routines, it's about finding guilty code.

Suppose you have a sampler that stroboscopically X-rays the program at random wall-clock times. In each sample, the program may be in the middle of I/O, it may be in code that you compiled, it may be in some library routine like **malloc**.

But no matter where it is, [the responsibility for it spending that slice of time is jointly shared by every line of code on the call stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343), because if any one of those calls had not been made, it would not be in the process of carrying out the work requested by that call.

So look at every line of code that shows up on multiple samples of the call stack (the more samples it is on, the better). That's where the money is. Don't just look where the program counter is. There are "deep pockets" higher up the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Yes those "seconds" values <strike>are</strike> aren't per call. The percentage time is for the entire run of the program. In effect your program spent 31% of it's time in that function (due to number of calls + time taken per call).

You might want to [read up](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof.html#SEC5) on how to analyze gprof's flat profiles.

**Correction:** Sorry, those first two seconds values are cumulative as pointed out by the OP.

I think that it's odd that you're seeing 0 for "self" and "total s/call".

Quoting the section on [gprof accuracy](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof.html#SEC12): "The actual amount of error is usually more than one sampling period. In fact, if a value is n times the sampling period, the expected error in it is the square-root of n sampling periods. If the sampling period is 0.01 seconds and foo's run-time is 1 second, the expected error in foo's run-time is 0.1 seconds. It is likely to vary this much on the average from one profiling run to the next. (Sometimes it will vary more.)"

Also, possibly related, it might be worth noting that gprof doesn't profile multithreaded programs. You're better off using something like [Sysprof](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~sandmann/sysprof/) or [OProfile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/) in such cases.

Comment: But that couldn't be: if it's called 5498021 times, then it should have taken 0.32s * 5498021 ~ 20 days! Also, the link is unclear (I read it before) - "This is the number of seconds accounted for by this function alone" seems to indicate a total, not per-call, but isn't clear.